# download json file and store locally on my android device

Tags: java, android, json

I am doing a rest call and getting a json file from the server by this

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("someurl");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream source = entity.getContent();
```

now i want to store this into a local file I am using FileOutputStream to do this but the problem is how to effectively convert the inputstream to outputstream if i am using something like this

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            int nextChar;
            while ((nextChar = source.read()) != -1) {
                fos.write((char) nextChar);
                System.out.println((char) nextChar);
                fos.flush();
            }
```

it is storing very slow the file which i am getting is upto 100kb is there any other faster method or any other way which i can use to store the json file in my device?

My applications uses this json heavily and i don't want to call the REST each time.

thanks
Pranay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils's

```
    IOUtils.copy(is,fos);
```

lets see, what happening. Thanks,

EDIT: Why not you are use sqlite database? parse JSON result onetime and insert it in database only onetime stuff then always you get fast execution.

EDIT: try android's internal storage for write json file

```
  try {      
       FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        fos.write(myJSONString.getBytes());
         fos.close();      
       //Log.d(TAG, "Written to file");  
     } 
   catch (Exception e)
     {    
        Log.d(TAG, "cought");     
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }
```

Comment: i get this error The import org.apache.commons.io cannot be resolved. Why i am not using sqllite is my json needs to be updated everyday i am using jakson which gives me pojo which is very fast so i dont need to go through a additional conversion from my json to sqllite

Comment: download jar file of org.apache.commons.io and the use that jar file in your build path using import jar.

Comment: thanks it work very well one question since the library is 270 kb is there any way in which i can remove the unused part? I know i can use progaurd in android is there any other alternative as i dont really need a obfuscated code

Comment: Try to download the source code of this library if available, after that removed unuseful class from that and create the new jar file then you can use it. Thanks.